# another 04079: invalid trigger specification

Tags: join, plsql, triggers, insert, multiple-tables

The syntax of the trigger creation looks correct to me, but I have having a hard time finding what is setting off this error.
This purpose of this trigger is to populate two different tables after a source table has entries added to it. The tasks table gets rows added, and then the CADP_IMPORT and CADP_EXPORT tables get only columns that are NOT NULL populated from the corresponding columns in the tasks table. The same happens for the RAVE tables. The varcdesc variable is located on a table two joins away. This is what defines which set of external tables are to be copied to.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATEEXTERNAL
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON TASKS
  REFERENCE new as new old as old
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (:new.status like 'CODE VERBATIM #%')

DECLARE
  vareid    varchar2(50);
  varcdesc  varchar2(50);

BEGIN 
  vareid := externalid;
  select c.description into varcdesc from configurations c, jobs j, tasks t
    where t.jobid = j.id
    and   j.configurationid = c.id;
  IF varcdesc = 'CADP AE and MH Convention' 
      OR varcdesc = 'CADP CM Convention' THEN
    INSERT ALL
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.CADP_IMPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,TERM,FROMSYS,PROT,TYPE,DATASET,VARNAME,BATCH,PNO) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1,t.REF2,t.REF3,t.REF4,t.REF5,t.REF6,t.REF7)

    INTO IATEINTEGRATION.CADP_EXPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM,FROMSYS,PROT,TYPE,DATASET,VARNAME,BATCH,PNO)
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1,t.REF2,t.REF3,t.REF4,t.REF5,t.REF6,t.REF7);

    ELSE IF varcdesc = 'RAVE AE and MH Convention' 
    OR varcdesc = 'RAVE CM Convention' THEN
    INSERT ALL
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.RAVE_IMPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM_TERM,STUDY_ID) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1)
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.RAVE_EXPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM_TERM,STUDY_ID) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1);
     END IF;
     END;
```

Comment: Why you reference `t.` columns in your inserts? This is valid only for `INSERT ... SELECT`, not for `INSERT ... VALUES` one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATEEXTERNAL
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON TASKS
  REFERENCE new as t old as old
  FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (:new.status like 'CODE VERBATIM #%')

DECLARE
  vareid    varchar2(50);
  varcdesc  varchar2(50);

BEGIN 
  vareid := externalid;
  select c.description into varcdesc from configurations c, jobs j, tasks tsk
    where tsk.jobid = j.id
    and   j.configurationid = c.id;
  IF varcdesc = 'CADP AE and MH Convention' 
      OR varcdesc = 'CADP CM Convention' THEN
    INSERT ALL
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.CADP_IMPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,TERM,FROMSYS,PROT,TYPE,DATASET,VARNAME,BATCH,PNO) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1,t.REF2,t.REF3,t.REF4,t.REF5,t.REF6,t.REF7)

    INTO IATEINTEGRATION.CADP_EXPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM,FROMSYS,PROT,TYPE,DATASET,VARNAME,BATCH,PNO)
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1,t.REF2,t.REF3,t.REF4,t.REF5,t.REF6,t.REF7);

    ELSE IF varcdesc = 'RAVE AE and MH Convention' 
    OR varcdesc = 'RAVE CM Convention' THEN
    INSERT ALL
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.RAVE_IMPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM_TERM,STUDY_ID) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1)
      INTO IATINTEGRATION.RAVE_EXPORT 
        (EXTERNALID,VERBATIM_TERM,STUDY_ID) 
      VALUES
        (vareid,t.verbatim,t.REF1);
     END IF;
     END;
```